# convert nested list to int or str

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following list structure:

```
the_given_list = [[[1],[2],[3]],[[1],[2],[3]]]
```

Indeed `len(the_given_list)` returns 2.
I need to make the following list:

```
the_given_list = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[sum(x, []) for x in the_given_list]
```

---

Flatten the first-order element in `the_given_list`.

```
the_given_list = [sum(x, []) for x in the_given_list]
print(the_given_list)
```

Comment: @PersianGulf it works for me. which part is not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

To explain the above answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57369395/1465553, this list

```
[[[1],[2],[3]],[[1],[2],[3]]]
```

can be seen as

```
[list1, list2]
```

and,

```
>> sum([[1],[2],[3]], [])
[1,2,3]
>>> sum([[1],[2],[3]], [5])
[5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Since the second argument to method `sum` defaults to `0`, we need to explicitly pass empty list `[]` to it to overcome type mismatch (between int and list).

https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/sum/

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
In [15]: from itertools import chain                                                                                                                                                                        

In [16]: [list(chain(*i)) for i in the_given_list]                                                                                                                                                          
Out[16]: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
the_given_list  = [ [ s[0] for s in f ] for f in the_given_list ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
the_given_list = [[[1],[2],[3]],[[1],[2],[3]]]
print([[j for sub in i for j in sub] for i in the_given_list])
```

Gives me:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Check the original answer on list flattening:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/5501407